# Salesforce Lightning: ondblclick event not working on Select List box

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

**ListBox.cmp**

```
<div id="div1" >
<label for="picklist">Available Labels</label> <br/>
 <select style="width:100%" id="picklist"  multiple="multiple" ondblclick="myFunction()">
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.GenreList}" var="opts">
       <option  value="{!opts}"> {!opts.value} </option>
   </aura:iteration>     
 </select> 
</div>
```

**ListBox.controller**

```
myFunction: function(component, event, helper){
    alert("hi");
   var a= event.get("{!opts}");
    alert(a);

}
```

when i double click on any options control is not going inside myFunction.

Comment: click handler on `select` tag should call function as `ondblclick={!c.myFunction}"`

Answer (score 1):

Double click handler on `select` tag should call client side controller function as `ondblclick={!c.myFunction}"`.

Read more in Lightning Components Developer Guide: [Handling Events with Client-Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm)

Comment: yes correct.now its working

Comment: @Rahul..I want to fetch double click option value in myFunction() method in controller.how to get it.